# Dropdown first value is empty in select attribute magento 2

Tags: magento2, attributes

I am getting dropdown custom attribute option values from database in foreach loop.But it show the very first value empty in select option.How i can skip this first empty value.

```
 <?php    //FOR MULTISELECT
         foreach ($groupCollection as $group) {
            array_push($groupIds, $group->getAttributeGroupId());
            $groupAttributesCollection = $cole->create()
                ->setAttributeGroupFilter($group->getId())
                ->addVisibleFilter()
                ->addFieldToFilter('is_user_defined', array('eq' => 1))
                ->addFieldToFilter('frontend_input', array('eq' => 'multiselect'))
                    ->load(); // product attribute collection
            foreach ($groupAttributesCollection->getItems() as $attribute) {
                ?>  <div class="row form-row radio-buttons-custom">  <?php
                array_push($attributeids, $attribute->getAttributeId());
                $opte=$attribute->getStoreLabel();
                ?>      <label><?php echo $opte;?></label> <?php
                array_push($somearray, $attribute->getid());
                $opt=$attribute->getid();
                $optionss=$block->getattributeoptions($opt);
                ?>
               <?php  $opte; ?><?php
                foreach($optionss as $valuess){
                    ?>
                    <label class="container"><?php echo $valuess['label'].':'; ?>
                    <input type="radio"  name="<?php echo $valuess['label']; ?>">
                    <span class="checkmark"></span>
                    </label>
                    <?php } ?>

                </div><?php
                   }
 } ?>
```

[image]

Comment: You can put a condition to check whether the attribute has label/value in $groupAttributesCollection->getItems() loop.
For example :  if($attribute->getStoreLabel()){
//Your code here
}